# Trying to extract all IP addresses from a file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, network-programming

I'm trying to extract all IP addresses from a file where the IP addresses are all in random positions, with there sometimes being more than one IP on a line.  It's a text file with the contents looking like the below:

```
hello9.9.9.9                     hdi3ohdoi3hoi3oid2         10.3.2.3            2.3.4.5
ddjeijfdeio
eifhoehjwiehfiowe
uiewhduihewiudhue
8.8.8.8, 20.20.20.20
de2hd9j39ud9829d8 192.168.10.24
```

My code only returns the first ip address on each line,

```
['9.9.9.9', '8.8.8.8', '192.168.10.24']
```

My code is below:

```
with open('C:/testfile.txt') as fh:
    file = fh.readlines()

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})')

lst = []

for line in file:
    match = pattern.search(line)
    if match is not None:
        lst.append(match[0])

print(lst)
```

How can I list all IP's of each line ? ( not only the first ? )

Comment: Use `pattern.findall(line)` to get a list of all matches on the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `pattern.findall()` to find all occurencess. Otherwise it will find first occurences.

```
import re

with open('testfile.txt') as fh:
    file = fh.readlines()

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})')

lst = []
for line in file:
    match = pattern.findall(line)
    if len(match) != 0:
        lst.extend(match)
print(lst)
```

output:

`['9.9.9.9', '10.3.2.3', '2.3.4.5', '8.8.8.8','20.20.20.20','192.168.10.24']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall`  for that:

```
import re

data = """
hello9.9.9.9                     hdi3ohdoi3hoi3oid2         10.3.2.3            2.3.4.5
ddjeijfdeio
eifhoehjwiehfiowe
uiewhduihewiudhue
8.8.8.8, 20.20.20.20
de2hd9j39ud9829d8 192.168.10.24
"""

result = re.findall(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', data)
print(result)
```

Result:

```
['9.9.9.9', '10.3.2.3', '2.3.4.5', '8.8.8.8', '20.20.20.20', '192.168.10.24']
```

Answer (score 0):

the **pattern.search** function is only searching for the first occurrence,

so I suggest to use the **findall** method instead of the search method so your code could look like:

```py
with open('C:/testfile.txt') as fh:
    file = fh.readlines()

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})')

lst = []

for line in file:
    match = re.findall(pattern,text)
    #match = pattern.findall(line)#searching for first one
    if match is not None:
        for x in match:#iter and add
            lst.append(x)
    #or 
        #lst.extend(match)#adds a list to the list

print(lst)
```